# Can't Enable "GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks" in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I am using OpenGL ES 3.0 with Android, and I am compiling two shaders:

**vertex shader:**

```
#version 300 es
#extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix;
uniform mat4 ml_matrix;

out DATA {
    vec2 position;
    vec4 color;
    vec2 uv;
} vs_out;

void main() {
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    vs_out.position = position;
    vs_out.color = color;
    vs_out.uv = uv;
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```
#version 300 es
#extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks : enable

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D tex;

in DATA {
    vec2 position;
    vec4 color;
    vec2 uv;
} frag_in;

void main() {
    float dist = length(frag_in.position);
    color = frag_in.color;
}
```

Even though I am enabling the GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks extension for both shaders, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:12: 'DATA' : requires extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks to be enabled 
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.

ERROR: 0:8: 'DATA' : requires extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks to be enabled 
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

I also tried

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks : require
```

which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the extension specification, the IO Blocks extension requires OpenGL ES 3.10 Shading Language.

Try using `#version 310 es`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but after this, I got an error about defining the precision. I had to add in "precision mediump float;" to the frag shader to fix it. However, I didn't need this if I didn't use the DATA struct in the shader. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: You should always  need a precision qualifier for that shader (e.g. your "float dist" definition doesn't contain a precision so that should error too).